# Mysql Select to columns as one but display only one where value %like%

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

I am trying to search two columns where value is alike and only display the data of the column that has the value not the other column, both columns can not contain the same value.

My code

```
SELECT CONCAT(`fname`,`lname`)as name ,date  
       FROM `table` WHERE id='1' AND CONCAT(`fname`,`lname`) LIKE '%james%' 
       ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0,1
```

The current query outputs both fname and last name value where it finds the %like% i just want it to output only the column where the %like% is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
   WHEN fname LIKE '%james%'
   THEN fname
   ELSE lname
END 
AS name
FROM `table`
WHERE id='1' AND CONCAT(`fname`,`lname`) LIKE '%james%' 
ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: CASE WHEN fname LIKE '%james%'
THEN fname
ELSE lname
END `AS name, date` works as expected thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(if(fname, fname, ""), if(lname, lname, "")) as name, date ...
```

Comment: The cell for Name returns Null empty?